Instantiate different classes according to different compilation flag of same header file in c++
I have a class that varies according to a compilation flag.
I would like to instantiate both the versions of the class in the same scope.
my_class.h

#ifndef MY_CLASS_H
#define MY_CLASS_H

#ifdef COMP_FLAG
#define MY_CLASS MyClassFlagged
#else
#define MY_CLASS MyClassNotFlagged
#endif

class MY_CLASS
{
};

#endif

Then, I have created two header files:
my_class_flagged.h and my_class_not_flagged.h
my_class_flagged.h

#ifndef MY_CLASS_FLAGGED
#define MY_CLASS_FLAGGED

#include "my_class.h"

#endif

my_class_not_flagged.h

#ifndef MY_CLASS_NOT_FLAGGED
#define MY_CLASS_NOT_FLAGGED

#include "my_class.h"

#endif

I am using bazel as build system, so I have compiled them with COMP_FLAG and without it to create two separate targets.
BUILD

cc_library(
    name = "not_flagged",
    hdrs = ["my_class.h"],
)

cc_library(
    name = "flagged",
    hdrs = ["my_class.h"],
    defines = ["COMP_FLAG"],
)

cc_library(
    name = "my_class_flagged",
    hdrs = ["my_class_flagged.h"],
    deps = [":flagged"],
)

cc_library(
    name = "my_class_not_flagged",
    hdrs = ["my_class_not_flagged.h"],
    deps = [":not_flagged"],
)

Then I am not able to instantiate both of them but only one:
#include "my_class_flagged.h"
#include "my_class_not_flagged.h"

// NOT BUILD
TEST(MyClassNotFlaggedTest, NotFlaggedInstantiation)
{
    MyClassNotFlagged my_class_not_flagged;
    std::ignore = my_class_not_flagged;
}

// PASS
TEST(MyClassFlaggedTest, FlaggedInstantiation)
{
    MyClassFlagged my_class_flagged;
    std::ignore = my_class_flagged;
}

obtaining this error:
error: 'MyClassNotFlagged' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'MyClassFlagged'?
where I have used:
cc_test(
    name = "test",
    srcs = ["test.cpp"],
    deps = [
        ":my_class_flagged",
        ":my_class_not_flagged",
    ],
)

Solution Attempts
[463035818_is_not_an_ai] Problem with include guards
I have tried to modify my_class.h file:
#ifdef COMP_FLAG
#ifndef MY_CLASS_FLAGGED_H
#define MY_CLASS_FLAGGED_H

#define MY_CLASS MyClassFlagged

class MY_CLASS
{
};

#endif  // MY_CLASS_FLAGGED_H
#else
#ifndef MY_CLASS_NOT_FLAGGED_H
#define MY_CLASS_NOT_FLAGGED_H

#define MY_CLASS MyClassNotFlagged

class MY_CLASS
{
};

#endif  // MY_CLASS_NOT_FLAGGED_H
#endif

However, now I got both test not building:
error: 'MyClassNotFlagged' was not declared in this scope
error: 'MyClassFlagged' was not declared in this scope.

how is it not working? What problem did you encounter?

Also show us the relevant content of my_class_flagged.h and my_class_not_flagged.h. BTW - #inlude with a single quote (') is not familiar to me.

#include 'my_class_flagged.h' doesnt look like a proper include directive, otherwise the code you posted looks fine. Please prepare a [mcve] and include any errors in the question

A same class cannot be defined more than once in the same translation file. What do you mean by version of same class. They can't be same. You can use templates. It is not clear what you mean here. Kindly provide a [mcve]. You say "Instantiate same class different compilation flag" but in your question you've different classes.

What are the contents of my_class_flagged.h and its unflagged counterpart? Is it anything other than a #define and an #include of my_class.h?

@user12002570 they define two different classes

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Yes, I see that that is why I asked. They said in their question "both the versions of the class" and "Instantiate same class different". See the updated comment.

MYC_CLASS is probably the problem.  Fix the typo.  Does the problem resolve?

I have updated the post. I thought that in this way the compiler can create two different object files during compilation and this would have not created problem in linking phase.
However, it is like it compiles using only one compilation flag.
If I try building the header files above mentioned it works.

@Eljay  thanks for spotting. Unfortunately this is just a simplified version of my original problem.

In that case, a [mcve] would be most helpful, rather than example code that does not reproduce the problem.  (Help us help you.)

when you make a simplified example, make sure to go the full way, try to compile it and see what happens. As long as you only show us code that has other unrelated typos, like eg #include 'my_class_flagged.h', the code you show us is not the code that has the issue you need help with, ergo we cannot help you with your actual issue

thanks for all of your suggestions, I have improved the question and now I think is much better.

the compiler error message is missing

your my_class.h has header guards, which means after you included my_class_flagged.h then including my_class_not_flagged.h wont see contents of my_class.h.

what is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Why do you need two distinct classes that have different name but are identical otherwise?

in my actual problem MyClass is way more complex and according to the compilation flag some methods changes a little.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai thanks for this intuition. I have tried a workaround based on it and I will post it

as has been mentioned already, C++ has templates, and I am almost certain that what you want can be done much more easily within the language as compared to outside of the language. Anything you do with the preprocessor is arcane and (almost) everything you do with your build system is specific to your build system, while using templates for the same would work everywhere

I dont get the point of the last edit. Instead of one include guard you now have two of them.... and MY_CLASS appears now twice

you are totally right, the problem is that unfortunately, I am dealing with legacy code. The code works pretty well since the changes are very minimal.  For testing purposes, I would need to instantiate both classes in the same scope and it's only here that I am getting trouble.

yes my idea, was trying to have conditional include guards based on the compilation flag. if I remove them I got problem with multiple definitions

In your updated code example, why does my_class.h have header guards, since it may be included multiple times?  How come my_class_flagged.h does not have #define COMP_FLAG?  Did you test this example code to ensure it repros your problem?

@KamilCuk thanks for the suggestions, unfortunately, I think this approach would require me to define both the MyClassFlagged and MyClassNotFlagged. I would like to flag the class without redefining anything.

@eljay my_class_flagged.h doesn't have the #define COMP_FLAG because it includes the :flagged target in the BUILD file that contains it. I have tried adding it, and I get redefining issue

I have no knowledge of Bazel.  I don't see how Bazel can define the flag for one header file and not define the flag for the other header file in a single translation unit.

I am afraid this isn't the answer, because from comments it is already apparent that your example is too much simplified. Anyhow, it appears you make something very simple into something complicated. Use the language when you can, only resort to conditional compilation using the preprocessor when needed. Nothing in your example really needs the preprocessor.
You can define one class template:
template <int tag> 
struct MY_CLASS {};   

using MyClassFlagged = MY_CLASS<0>;
using MyClassNotFlagged = MY_CLASS<1>;

There are ways to determine the difference between this approach and defining two separate (non-template) classes, but for most uses and applications that difference should not matter.

If you want to stay with the preprocessor (for whatever reasons) then I suggest to at least leave the build system out. Include the header twice, define and undefine the flag explicitly in your code.
In the my_class_flagged.h write:
#ifndef MY_CLASS_FLAGGED
#define MY_CLASS_FLAGGED

#define COMP_FLAG
#include "my_class.h"
#undef COMP_FLAG

#endif

And in my_class_not_flagged.h write:
#ifndef MY_CLASS_NOT_FLAGGED
#define MY_CLASS_NOT_FLAGGED

#include "my_class.h"

#endif

And remove the include guards from my_class.h. And I suggest to rename it to eg my_class.x or whatever you like different from .h to indicate it shall not be included directly.
And, in my_class.h as the last line before closing the header guard, add:
#undef MY_CLASS

If you do that, you can include both headers (in any order) in main.cpp to have both classes defined.
Live Demo

unfortunately, this doesn't solve my original question, I like this approach and I would like to be able to templatize that class. Thanks.

@FrancescoVezzi as mentioned, I am convinced we are looking at a XY problem and I think it would help if rather than asking about what you think could be a solution tell us about the actual problem. Anyhow, the question went through some iterations and I honestly think this is an answer for the question as it stands now. At least nothing in your question would indicate that it isnt.

@FrancescoVezzi I added a non-template approach more similar to yours

thank you very much, I have tried it, but I still have the same issue:
error: 'MyClassNotFlagged' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'MyClassFlagged'

maybe it's just impossible

maybe you are still compiling code that is different from what yuo show here, or you didnt follow my instructions properly. DId you remove the include guards from my_class.h ?

I am trying with the code above mentioned, and yes I forgot to remove include guards. However I still get this redefinition error:
error: "MY_CLASS" redefined #define MY_CLASS MyClassNotFlagged
note: this is the location of the previous definition     5 | #define MY_CLASS MyClassFlagged

this is the one-file-equivalent of the solution I propose https://godbolt.org/z/KcqW1x4rf. It does have an error, but was not declared is not the first

@FrancescoVezzi I added the fix.
